# git go back to a previous commit

Tags: git

I have the following situation. 
A commit where my project works. 
The next commit where something horrible that I can not explain happens. 
So

```
badcommit (HEAD->master) How horrible!
goodcommit Here it works
```

so I did `git checkout goodcommit` and I got my project working again! (pheew!).

```
 goodcommit(HEAD) Here it works
```

So now I want to start from here and forget that horrible experience. I read you can revert a commit. So How can I put master in goodcommit and continue from there?

(I read very complicated answers but I remember it was very simple: a one line command that took the last commit and reverted to the previous one, not -like I read- a series of complicated commands)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to revert a Git repository to a previous commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114095/how-to-revert-a-git-repository-to-a-previous-commit)

Comment: You've checked out the good commit. Now create a branch at that point and keep going, or reset the old branch to the good commit.

Comment: @evolutionxbox Yeah I could do that but would lose the master branch. So revert is needed

Comment: Why would you lose the master branch? Have you made many commits since the bad one?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/51814990/1256452 as well. This particular question and its answers is/are intended for: "we've been working for a week, made dozens of commits, and now we all need to go back to one-week-ago". For your particular simple case you just want one `git revert` or `git reset`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use following commands,

`git log`

It will provide you list of your previous commits, copy that long string from the commit, then use

`$ git reset --hard <COMMIT -ID>`

Example: `git reset --hard 6504ab87416af0571ae628511207813f20bb2d2c`

That's it.

Comment: Answering duplicate questions isn't the best idea

Comment: @Neeraj Do I have to copy the whole number? I thought only the first 7

Comment: Maybe he is not finding the desired output or something might be not clear to him.

Comment: I am not sure. I always copy whole number but you can try your own trick and let me know if its working.

Comment: @Neeraj consider using "the OP" rather than "he" or "him".

Comment: @Neeraj Thanks. I ll try. (I am a "he" )

Comment: sure @evolutionxbox. Thanks. I will keep that in mind.